# Android Studio, Getting the Error 'cannot resolve method'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, error-handling

In My Block Of Code i am Suffering from the Error "Cannot resolve method 'putExtra(java.lang.String, android.widget.TextView)'". Ive Tried a few Things However i cannot get this fixed. Does Anyone Know what i could do to fix this, or an alternative piece of Code I Could Use?

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_message));
            shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to put text from TextView (txt_message) to bundle - just put text from it like this (not a TextView):

```
TextView txt_message = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_message);
String text = txt_message.getText().toString();

Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uri);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code after intent:

```
Bundle extras = shareIntent.getExtras();
String exampleString = extras.getString(ProjectManager.ID);
```